# Matplotlib Text in Table not centered

Tags: python, matplotlib, datatable

I tried several methods but can't figure out how to properly center the text in the columns and tighten all of it. Help would be much appreciated.

```
plt.close()
colors = []
for _, row in mail_decision_table.iterrows():
    colors_in_column = ["aliceblue", "lightgrey"]
    if row["Decision"]=="SELL":
        colors_in_column[1] = "lightcoral"
    else:
        colors_in_column[1] = "lightgreen"
    colors.append(colors_in_column)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')



the_table = ax.table(cellText = mail_decision_table.values,
    colLabels = mail_decision_table.columns,
    loc='center',
    rowLoc='center',
    colColours = ["grey","grey"],
    cellColours=colors)


for key, cell in the_table.get_celld().items():
    cell.set_linewidth(0.5)
    cell.set_linestyle("dashed")
    cell.set_edgecolor("grey")
    cell._loc = 'center'
    if key[0] ==0 :
        cell._text.set_color('white')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `cellLoc='center'` option to your `the_table` variable:

```
the_table = ax.table(cellText = mail_decision_table.values,
    colLabels = mail_decision_table.columns,
    loc='center',
    cellLoc='center',
    rowLoc='center',
    colColours = ["grey","grey"],
    cellColours=colors)
```